# Htaccess redirect from www to non-www, HTTP to HTTPS, and index.php to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect url variations so that something like this:
http://www.example.com/index.php

redirects simply to: https://example.com
(ie http to https; www to non-www; and index.php to root of the domain)

```
    # Canonical HTTPS/non-WWW
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example/$1 [L,R=301]

    # direct /index.php to /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ 
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L] 
    </IfModule>
```

Question:
Is there a more elegant solution that combines the two?

Answer (score 0):

The code above for redirecting from www to non-www and from HTTP to HTTPS is correct and will always deliver the client to the correct address through one redirect. However, redirecting /index.php to / after that can result in a needless additional redirect.

ie. if history will go like this:

```
> http://www.example.com/index.php [301]
> https://example.com/index.php [301]
> https://example.com/ [200]
```

You can fix this by simply reversing the order just like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# direct /index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ https://example/%1 [R=301,L]

# Canonical HTTPS/non-WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried reversing the order but the index.php is not removed as a result.

Comment: The syntax you're using at line 8 in your code is incorrect 
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ `

Try copying my code instead

Comment: Ok. I copied your code and tried it on another site. Only diff is that I require www. here. The index.php refuses to disappear.

Comment: What version of apache are you using?

Comment: I updated my code. Please try again and tell me how it goes

Comment: On this shared server, Apache's version is not shown. Anyway, your solution worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Spoke too soon! Worked great on the frontend. The backend (this is a Joomla site), I was unable to login. Had to remove the redirection for index.php.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. :) If my answer helped you, I would appreciate if you can check my answer as a correct answer